# Code for inviting friends

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-apps

I need a code for inviting friends to a fanpage.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
This is linking to the website. Is it possible to link to my fb fanpage?

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you read the whole documents, that Request feature is for Facebook Application only. But here's a work around :

- Create a Facebook Application
- Have a great content where everyone wants to have
- Put a Like Gate before they can access your great content
- You can still use the App Request for your app while the user likes your page